# Extracting list of addresses in particular region from OpenStreetMap (OSM) data?

Tags: openstreetmap, address

I need to extract all addresses in particular region from OpenStreetMap (OSM) data.

Is it possible to do this?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! Would you be able to edit your question to provide some details about where you have looked before posting your question, please?  I would be surprised if this question has not been asked and answered here before.

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at the [Overpass API](http://overpass-api.de/).

It is designed for regional and thematic filtered download of OSM data.

Keep in mind that the address coverage in OSM varies from country to country.

Comment: This won't work for retrieving full address information. Many addresses in OSM only include partial information, e.g. only street and house number. For obtaining full addresses a post-processing step is required. This is for example done by [Nominatim](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim) which uses additional information like administrative borders in order to determine the city, county, state and so on.